# escape character for round and square brackets in powershell

Tags: powershell, brackets

I am trying to split an array with the delimiter containing round brackets and square brackets, however i tried with different combination of tricks but didn't work.
This is a 1d array I am trying to process

**$Array**

```
process-a.exe[80]: in process 
process-b.exe[30]: failed:retrying
process-c.exe[40]: in process 
process-y.exe:(sub-process-e.exe[20]): failed:suspended
process-z.exe:(sub-process-f.exe[30]): in process 
process-g.exe[10]: completed
```

And this is a 2d array i expect after splitting

**Expected outcome**

```
process name                                p_id    status
------------------------------------------------
process-a.exe[80]:                          80      in process
process-b.exe[30]:                          30      failed:retrying
process-c.exe[40]:                          40      in process
process-y.exe[1]:(sub-process-e.exe[20]):   20      failed:suspended
process-z.exe[1]:(sub-process-f.exe[30]):   30      in process
process-g.exe[10]:                          10      completed
```

**Here are the stuff i have tried**

***1. escape characters***

backslash  \

```
$proc = $proc | % { $_ -split '\]:'}
```

back ticks `

```
$proc = $proc | % { $_ -split '`]:'}
```

***2. quotes***

single quotes ''

```
$proc = $proc | % { $_ -split '`]:'}
```

double quotes ""

```
$proc = $proc | % { $_ -split "\]:"}
```

**3. methods**

```
$delim1 = '):'
$delim2 = ']:'
```

RegEx

```
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Escape($delim1)
```

Wildcard

```
[WildcardPattern]::Escape($demin1)
```

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to end up with?

Comment: splitting the 1d array into the 2d array with 3 columns (p_name, p_id, status), just like the table shown in "Expected outcome"

Comment: You're not going to be able to use the p_id in two columns with split without some logic.

Comment: yes, but first I have to split out processName and status, which I am already stuck at as I can't use ): and ]: as deliminator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to use the data in more than one column, splitting does not seem like the best approach. Regex should help you achieve your desired results more easily.

String array

```
$array = 'process-a.exe[80]: in process',
         'process-b.exe[30]: failed:retrying',
         'process-c.exe[40]: in process',
         'process-y.exe:(sub-process-e.exe[20]): failed:suspended',
         'process-z.exe:(sub-process-f.exe[30]): in process',
         'process-g.exe[10]: completed'
```

Switch statement with regex pattern matching

```
switch -Regex ($array){
    '^(.+\[(.+)\].{0,}:) (.+)$' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'process name' = $matches.1
            p_id           = $matches.2
            status         = $matches.3
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
process name                           p_id status          
------------                           ---- ------          
process-a.exe[80]:                     80   in process      
process-b.exe[30]:                     30   failed:retrying 
process-c.exe[40]:                     40   in process      
process-y.exe:(sub-process-e.exe[20]): 20   failed:suspended
process-z.exe:(sub-process-f.exe[30]): 30   in process      
process-g.exe[10]:                     10   completed
```

**Regex explanation**

`^` beginning of the line

`()` capture groups

`.+` match one or more of any character

`\[` literal square brackets, escaped

`.{0,}` match zero or more of any character

`$` end of the line

If this text is in a file then simply change the switch to

```
switch -Regex -File ($filepath){
    '^(.+\[(.+)\].{0,}:) (.+)$' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'process name' = $matches.1
            p_id           = $matches.2
            status         = $matches.3
        }
    }
}
```

You can assign all the switch output to a variable by putting the variable assignment before the switch statement.

**Edit**

Based on your comment with extra details that would ideally be added to your post, I've made the following adjustment

```
switch -Regex ($array){
    '^(.+\[(.+)\].+?) (.+)$' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'process name' = $matches.1
            p_id           = $matches.2
            status         = $matches.3
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
process name                                                  p_id  status                                                               
------------                                                  ----  ------                                                               
process-a.exe[80]:                                            80    in process                                                           
process-b.exe[30]:                                            30    failed:retrying                                                      
process-c.exe[40]:                                            40    in process                                                           
process-y.exe:(sub-process-e.exe[20]):                        20    failed:suspended                                                     
process-z.exe:(sub-process-f.exe[30]):                        30    in process                                                           
process-g.exe[10]:                                            10    completed                                                            
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[53136]): 53136 Could not find uid associated with service: 0: Undefined error: 0 501
```

Comment: thanks Doug, I have implement the Regex to my script and it seems really close to what I am trying to do here, however I am not sure few lines were not match properly, I have tried hard to modify your regex but no luck, below is one of the example

Comment: **INPUT** `com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[53136]): Could not find uid associated with service: 0: Undefined error: 0 501`
**CURRENT-OUTPUT**
$matches.1`com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[53136]): Could not find uid associated with service: 0: Undefined error:`
$matches.2`53136`
$matches.3`0 501`
**EXPECT-OUTPUT**
$matches.1`com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[53136]): `
$matches.2`53136`
$matches.3`Could not find uid associated with service: 0: Undefined error:0 501`